# Command prompt for merging word documents

Tags: merge, ms-word, command

I have two word documents and I need to merge them into one word document using command prompt. Option copy *.extension newfile.extensions works with .txt or .csv file but if I do that with docx result of operation is corrupted word file.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to achieve what you want (with command copy) as merging two word documents is a bit more subtle than just do a 'bit wise append' (which is what the copy command does).

Google give quite a few result when searching for 'merge word documents'. One of the result might point you to a tool that you can invoke at the command line.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I need the result of merging use in navision so it' has to be automation.

Answer (score 0):

I have need of something similar, and this was the best I could find: https://github.com/jamessantiago/DocxMerge

I haven't tried it yet, but from all I can tell there is no command line option for combining Word documents.

(Good to know: The .docx file is actually a zip file. Rename it to .zip and unzip it to view what's inside. Combining two documents is tricky, but obviously possible, from command line. But there is no built-in command to do it.)